# can't connect to postgres on windows10

Tags: windows, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I am setting up project on my windows PC and I have a problem with postgres.
Project is set on docker.
when I run `docker-compose up` I receive error

```
: *** Failed to connect to database dev; trying to create database    
/usr/local/bundle/gems/sequel-4.48.0/lib/sequel/adapters/postgres.rb:224:in `initialize': PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: Connection refused (Sequel::DatabaseConnectionError)
Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Cannot assign requested address
Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

I don't know what to do. I have already installed microsoft easy-fix for TCP-IP, shut down windows firewall, changed all connection in `pg_hba.conf` to trust. Nothing helps. I don't have any antivirus software installed.

nmap report:

```
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.0027s latency).
Other addresses for localhost (not scanned): ::1
Not shown: 995 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
135/tcp  open  msrpc
445/tcp  open  microsoft-ds
2068/tcp open  avocentkvm
2179/tcp open  vmrdp
5432/tcp open  postgresql
```

edit:
I run `psql -h localhost` and received

```
psql: CATASTROPHIC: role "Kamil" does not exist
```

Kamil is my PC name.

## edit2:

is it possible that docker doesn't have access to postgres on localhost?

Comment: Did you start the Postgres service?

Comment: yes, it is running

Comment: Can you connect to the database with  `psql -U postgres -h 127.0.0.1` ?

Comment: login with `psql -h localhost -U postgres`

Comment: with `-U postgres` it works well

Comment: Are you trying to connect "from the outside" and if so is the server only listening on the local interface? (`listen_addresses` in "postgresql.conf")

Comment: I am connecting locally and `listen_addresses='*'`

Comment: Now I am wondering if it's not something wrong with docker

Comment: @Kamil Docker won't expose anything outside the container unless you explicitly specify it. The Postgres [image on Docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/) exposes the proper port.

Comment: @Kamil if your image doesn't already expose the port, add `--expose 5432` or `--expose 5432:5432` in your `docker run` command

Comment: @Kamil `docker ps` should show the port mappings of your container

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## problem solved

I had to set environment var to `DB_HOST=docker.for.win.localhost`

Comment: Nice that you solved your problem and great you shared the solution! (too many people just delete their question)

Comment: Where did you set that?

Comment: in docker-compose.yml file

Comment: can you share your docker-compose.yml file please ?

Comment: no, I dont have access to that file anymore